# I GET permission Error When I want to get data from bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In my project I create a service account and generate JSON key in use it in below script to get data from bigquery, I also give my service account and my dataset requirement permission (big query data editor) my billing and quate dont have problem too. but I get 403 forbidden permission error.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Set the path to your JSON key file
json_key_path = "C:/dear masood/alibaba-ga4-7aef9376a694.json"

# Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = json_key_path

from google.cloud import bigquery

# Create a BigQuery client
client = bigquery.Client()
# List datasets to confirm authentication works
datasets = list(client.list_datasets())

for dataset in datasets:
    print(f"Dataset ID: {dataset.dataset_id}")
```

Comment: In order to execute BigQuery jobs, you'll need the "bigquery.jobUser" role.

Comment: I tried to tidy your question up, but it still isn't very clear. Please read [ask], then [edit] to clarify.